# ElGamal message encryption

Tags: cryptography, encode, elgamal

I know that i have to encode any message in order to encrypt it using ElGamal cryptosystem. However, i know that's easy when you have a message of a pair of numbers, f.e (5,3). But if you have one like m=2, what should we do to use it as a pair?

Comment: ElGamal is just a Discrete Log-based crypto system. I'm not sure why you need a pair of numbers. What field are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is only about [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) without involving development.